# how to separate admin and user in angular project?

Tags: angular

I'm gonna to build a full project with angular , so i want to include the admin and the user in this project .

How to separate admin area and user in angular ? , also i want to separate the style files for each one how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use gulp Task runner to build free style folder structure and compile to one file in the end. 
Reference project 
[link](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-1-5-components-app)